# Convert Headers data in String to Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, http-headers

I have the HTTP headers data as a String as below.

```
{Accept=[*/*], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[273], content-type=[application/xml], host=[localhost:8090], SOAPAction=["http://someurl"]}
```

Splitting based on `','` leads to incorrect splitting as the values are also separated by `','`. I am not able to convert this to a `Map<String, List<String>>` or `MultivaluedMap<String, String>`.

Comment: Where/in what context are you getting these headers?

Comment: Extending Apache CXF LoggingInInterceptor returns the headers in this format.

Comment: Is that the one that's been deprecated for well over a year?

Comment: Plus, that doesn't appear to be correct; [the interface says it's a `Map`](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/Message.html), and you seem to just be printing the `toString()` instead of calling `get(ACCEPT_ENCODING)`

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes, that is the one. I call the method getHeader on loggingMessage and I get that value.

Comment: @user2761431 Does my answer below not solve your problem?

Comment: It does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values are always within `[` `]`, you can use a non-greedy regex to extract the headers and their values. Then, just split the values at `,` and add them to your `Map`.

```java
String input = "{Accept=[*/*], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[273], content-type=[application/xml], host=[localhost:8090], SOAPAction=[\"http://someurl\"]}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([-\\w]+)=\\[(.*?)]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String key = matcher.group(1);  // the header
    String val = matcher.group(2);  // its value

    map.put(key, Arrays.asList(val.split("\\s,\\s"))));
}

System.out.println(map);
```

**Output:**

```
{SOAPAction=["http://someurl"], Accept=[*/*], host=[localhost:8090], connection=[keep-alive], content-type=[application/xml], cache-control=[no-cache], Content-Length=[273], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br]}
```